# fragment transparent and overlay another fragment navigation drawer android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm using a navigation drawer in my application with `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. The problem is that my navigation menu is always transparent and sometimes when I change the fragment I can see the previous one behind the new one  "overlaying" (I said sometimes not always).

This is my main code:

```
public class Main extends FragmentActivity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private ImageLoader mLoader;

static String destinationFile;
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

private CharSequence mTitle;
private boolean isTracking = false;
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;
Bundle extras;
private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

String countnotif="";
static int mNotifCount = 0;
Boolean etat=false;
Bitmap btmap;
String myid,fbname;
String value;
CallbackManager callbackManager;

SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
public static final String MyPREFERENCES="My profile info";
public static final String keyid="myaccountid";
public static final String keypwd="myaccountpwd";
public static final String keyhotel="myhotelname";
public static final String keyidhotel="idH";
public static final String keynotifcount="countnotif";
public static final String keynotif="notifmsg";
public static final String keynotifmsg="notificationmsg";
private String myidhotel;
String myaccountname;
TextView myemail;

public static final String keyusername="myusername";
public static final String keymail="mymail";
TextView myname,mymail;
LinearLayout drawerll;
JSONArray thumburl = null;
static String imgfromurl;
String datapass;
ProfileTracker profileTracker;
ImageView myimage;
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    //save the fragment state here

    outState.putString("fbuser", myname.getText().toString());
    // outState.putString("fbmail",emailT.getText().toString());
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());

    setContentView(R.layout.tray);

     extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        value = extras.getString("hotelname");
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, "VALUE" + value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    forceShowActionBarOverflowMenu();
    final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
   // bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_pressed_want)));
    // getting items of slider from array
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // getting Navigation drawer icons from res 
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);


    drawerll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerll);


    myname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.usernameacount);
    myimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimg);

    myemail=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.usermailaccount);


    // adding nav drawer items to array
    // Home
    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    // Find People

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));

    // Photos
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    // Communities, Will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
    // Pages
    countnotif = sharedpreferences.getString(keynotifcount, "");

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1), etat, countnotif));

    // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(7, -1)));

    // Recycle array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting list adapter for Navigation Drawer
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Enable action bar icon_luncher as toggle Home Button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name) {

                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);


                    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                    // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bars icons
                       // onCreateOptionsMenu();
                    invalidateOptionsMenu(); //Setting, Refresh and Rate App
        }




        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);

                invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
          displayView(0);
    }



Intent intent = getIntent();

if (intent != null)
{

    try {

        Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
        datapass = data.getString("content");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception

    }
}




@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, data);
    if(extras!=null) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, data);
    }
}
/**
 * Slider menu item click listener
 * */
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected item
        displayView(position);


    }



}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();//getSupportMenuInflater();

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    RelativeLayout badgeLayout = (RelativeLayout) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_notif).getActionView();
    ImageView bell= (ImageView)badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.bell);


    if (sharedpreferences.contains(keynotifcount)) {
        countnotif = sharedpreferences.getString(keynotifcount, "");
        mNotifCount= Integer.parseInt(countnotif);
    }
    if(mNotifCount!=0) {
        TextView notifCount = (TextView) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_notifcation_textview);
        notifCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        notifCount.setText(String.valueOf(mNotifCount));
        etat=true;
    }
    if(mNotifCount==0) {
        TextView notifCount = (TextView) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_notifcation_textviewoff);
        etat=false;
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "notifcount" + mNotifCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    bell.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Management.class));
            displayView(4);


            etat=false;

            mNotifCount=0;

            countnotif= String.valueOf(mNotifCount);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(keynotifcount, countnotif);

            editor.commit();
        }
    });

   // return true;
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    //  title/icon
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_notif:
        return true;


    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

//called when invalidateOptionsMenu() invoke 

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if Navigation drawer is opened, hide the action items
    //boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawerll);

   // menu.findItem(R.id.menu_notif).setVisible(drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content with called Fragment
    //  new JSONParseimg().execute();

    Fragment fragment = new Fragment();

    //Fragment fragment = null;
 /*   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();*/



        case 0:

            fragment = new Home();
            break;
        case 1:

                fragment = new Profile();

            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new VraiCateg();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new MyLocation(); 
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new Notification();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new Share();
            break;
        case 6:
            fragment = new About();
            break;
        case 7:
            logout();
            Intent in = new Intent(this, Auth.class);
            startActivity(in);
            finish();


            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager= getSupportFragmentManager();
        // Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerll);

    } else {

        Log.e("this is mainActivity", "Error in else case");
    }

}


@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}


@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

private void forceShowActionBarOverflowMenu() {
    try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
        if (menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();       
         }
}
}
```

this is my first fragment:

```
public class VraiRela extends Fragment implements StaggeredGridView.OnItemClickListener {

ArrayList<VraiRelations> relationsList;
StaggeredAdapterVraiRelations adapter;
StaggeredGridView staggeredGridView;
String passtitle="";
public static final String inputFormat = "HH:mm:ss";
SimpleDateFormat inputParser = new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat, Locale.FRANCE);


SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
public static final String MyPREFERENCES="My profile info";
private String myidhotel;
public static final String keyidhotel="idH";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vrai_rela_main, container, false);

   myidhotel = getArguments().getString("idH");


        final String ref_type = getArguments().getString("ref_type");


    staggeredGridView = (StaggeredGridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

    relationsList = new ArrayList<VraiRelations>();

    StaggeredAdapterVraiRelations adapter = new StaggeredAdapterVraiRelations(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.layout.vrai_rela_list_item_sample,relationsList);
    staggeredGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    staggeredGridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    return view;
}




@Override
public void onItemClick(StaggeredGridView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      String ref_relation=relationsList.get(position).getRefrelation();
    Fragment newFragment = new RelationDetails();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Bundle args=new Bundle();
    args.putString("ref_relation",ref_relation);
    newFragment.setArguments(args);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "ref_relation"+ref_relation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    transaction.remove(VraiRela.this);
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, newFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    transaction.commit();
}

private Date parseDate(String date) {

    try {
        return inputParser.parse(date);
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        return new Date(0);
    }
}}
```

this is my layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff" >
<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawerll"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/list_item_pressed"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/blue_head_want"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/profile_head"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="135px"
            android:layout_height="135px"
            android:id="@+id/myimg"
        android:src="@drawable/profile" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/blue_head_name"
                android:id="@+id/usernameacount"
                android:textSize="9sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/usermailaccount"
                android:textColor="@color/blue_under_head_name"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="7sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/blue_under_head_name" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/list_background"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:textColor="@color/blue_item_name"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:alpha="255"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try to change the  android:background="@color/list_item_pressed" to  android:background="#ffffff"

Comment: @warlock i want to have this color when the item is pressed

Comment: If you want to change the color when button preses then you should use selector <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/confirm_selected" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/confirm_unselected"></item>

</selector>


That should be on your buttons background not on the layout.

Comment: @warloack ahh i have used it in listview  `android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"`so i should change the background from linearlayout??

Comment: it didn't solve the problem